# Using VLC command line to play DVD from a network folder display error

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, dvd

I am trying to play a DVD which was copied to a network folder on a server using the command line.  If I use the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"  dvd:// "\\Bts1\cctv\client\DVD 2"
```

It plays the DVD in VLC but I get an error message that says

```
Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc
Your input cant be opened
vlc is unable to open the MDL 'dvd://'. check the log for details
```

Why do get the error message but it still plays the DVD from the folder?